# insert multiple on key update those multiple

Tags: mysql, insert, duplicates

This is a common topic but i can't find my answer...
I have to insert or update 1000 records and what i want to do is this

```
INSERT INTO contacts
(contacts.tipo_contacto, 
contacts.date_entered, 
contacts.date_modified,
contacts.created_by, 
contacts.id)
VALUES ('INSERTED',now(), now(), 'MYSQL', '55ae1a2715c9a'), 
('INSERTED', now(), now(), 'MYSQL', '55ae1a2718a47') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
tipo_contacto='UPDATED', 
date_modified=now(), 
created_by='mysql' , 
tipo_contacto='UPDATED', 
date_modified=now(), 
created_by='mysql2'
```

the two key update should refer to diferent keys and they update the two of them the problem is they update it with the last value so both records get created_by='mysql2'
How do i change the values to different keys?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put an expression in the `on duplicate key update`:

```
INSERT INTO contacts(tipo_contacto, date_entered, date_modified, created_by, id) 
    VALUES ('INSERTED', now(), now(), 'MYSQL', '55ae1a2715c9a'), 
           ('INSERTED', now(), now(), 'MYSQL', '55ae1a2718a47') 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
        tipo_contacto = 'UPDATED',
        date_modified = now(),
        created_by = (case when VALUES(id) = '55ae1a2715c9a' then 'mysql' else 'mysql2' end);
```

Note: you don't qualify column names in the column list for an `insert`.

Comment: is that a good option i mean i have at least 20 fields to alter if it's update and 1000 records where  each has 20 lines like created_by... is it better to have like this?\n INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=3;
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (4,5,6)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=9;

Comment: @user3761919 . . . I don't know what you mean by "good option".  Normally, it would just be `created_by = values(created_by)`.  I don't know why you would want to change the value of the column from what is inserted.

Comment: its an update i want to know if it's trully updating, it works that way but i fear in php it would become too expensive to create it for 1000 records and specify each id

Answer (score 0):

In the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` clause you can use `VALUES(column_name)` to refer to the value which would of been inserted if there was no duplicate.

```
INSERT INTO contacts 
    (contacts.tipo_contacto, contacts.date_entered, contacts.date_modified, contacts.created_by, contacts.id) 
VALUES
    ('INSERTED', now(), now(), 'MYSQL', '55ae1a2715c9a'), 
    ('INSERTED', now(), now(), 'MYSQL', '55ae1a2718a47') 
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    tipo_contacto=VALUES(tipo_contacto), date_modified=VALUES(date_modified), created_by=VALUES(created_by)
```

Comment: I was assuming the data to be inserted is suppose to be updated if it exists.

Comment: and it is but the problem is both id's will have same data and it's not suposed too it updates with the last line of the update this "tipo_contacto='UPDATED', 
date_modified=now(), 
created_by='mysql2'"

Comment: Yes, but the row with `id= 55ae1a2718a47` has `created_by=MYSQL` (which I missed). So your update values differ from the insert.